# Only one file attribute changing if 10 search matched found also

Tags: loops, vbscript, attributes, filesystemobject

Issue: I'm trying to change attributes for files which having searched value then attributes change. Actually attributes are being changed for only one file not for all searched found. My requirement Check file attribute and search file string if found then replace attribute,else existing script.
Please go through below vbscript:

```
Dim fso, strFolder, file, path, strFilename, filesys, strSearch, readfile, objFile, fil, intCounter, strContent, objFS, objTS, strFileName1, strdate, objLogs, strHome, cap, cap1, cap12,cap9

'Submission Folder

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFileName1 = "D:\verify\SG_Script_" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now) & "-" & Year(Now) & ".Log"
sms = FormatDateTime(Time, 4)
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForAppending = 8
Count = 0

Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Submission Folder
Dir = "D:\verify\files\"
' Check that the strDirectory folder exists
If fso.FolderExists(Dir) Then
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(Dir)
    cap = " Submission folder accessible "
    strContent = "" & Date & Space(1) & sms & Space(1) & cap & Dir
    Set objLogs = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, ForAppending, True)
    objLogs.WriteLine (strContent)
    objLogs.Close
Else
    cap1 = " Submission folder unavailable,exiting script, Submission folder unavailble. "
    strContent = "" & Date & Space(1) & sms & Space(1) & cap1 & Space(2) & Dir
    Set objLogs = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, ForAppending, True)
    objLogs.WriteLine (strContent)
    objLogs.Close
    wscript.Quit
End If

'submission folder

Dim StrDestinationLocation, objfso
StrDestinationLocation = "D:\verify\backup\"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(Dir)
If Not fso.FolderExists(StrDestinationLocation) Then
    fso.CreateFolder StrDestinationLocation
    cap9 = " Backup Process: New folder created due to unavailblity of backup folder at"
    strContent = "" & Date & Space(1) & sms & Space(2) & cap9 & Space(2) & StrDestinationLocation
    Set objLogs = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, ForAppending, True)
    objLogs.WriteLine (strContent)
    objLogs.Close
End If

'attribute search

path = "D:\verify\files"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set path = fso.GetFolder(path).Files

For Each file In path

    If file.Attributes = "32" Then

        MsgBox "match Found"

        Dim sSearchString1, sSearchString2, sSearchString3, sSearchString4, extension
        sSearchString1 = "<AuthorIDNew>1111</AuthorIDNew>"
        sSearchString2 = "<AuthorName>He, she</AuthorName>"
        sSearchString3 = " <AuthorIDNew>2222</AuthorIDNew>"
        sSearchString4 = "<AuthorName>An, and</AuthorName>"
        extension = "xml"

        Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(Dir)
        For Each fil In oFolder.Files
            Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.path, ForReading)
            strname1 = fso.GetFileName(fil)
            sReadAll = oFile.ReadAll
            oFile.Close
            If InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString1) > 0 Or _
                InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString2) > 0 Or _
                InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString3) > 0 Or _
                InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString4) > 0 Then
                Count = Count + 1
                fso.CopyFile fil.path, StrDestinationLocation

                'changing attribute
                file.Attributes = file.Attributes + 32
                cap12 = " Backup Success"
                strContent = "" & Date & Space(1) & sms & Space(1) & cap12 & Space(2) & strname1
                Set objLogs = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, ForAppending, True)
                objLogs.WriteLine (strContent)
                objLogs.Close
            End If
        Next

    'if file attribute 32 and search value not found

    Else

        MsgBox "no match Found"

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Can anyone look on this

Comment: As a start, try `Dim`ming what you used, many of those aren't used at all and some are declared but do not appear. It looks like you've taken snippets from different scripts and put them together in your post above without really understanding how to best do so.

Comment: I tried using this line after search and copying file, file.Attributes = file.Attributes + 32  it's only changing attribute to one file not all the files

Comment: Adding further information before you have fixed your general script structure etc. and edited your question accordingly will not compel me to reply.

Comment: @Compo  it's done pls have look and suggest me

Comment: You have somehow ruined the formatting of the code block in your script…`If file.attributes and 32 Then`

Comment: @Compo plz suggest me how to fix

Comment: Remove all of that code, take your entire script, paste it in then press `Ctrl + K`

Comment: There are 4 instances of `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, you need only one. Put `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` once at the beginning of the script, and remove other lines with `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. Replace `objFS` with `fso`.

Comment: :) working fine now

Comment: finally Resolved                                                                 
    object.Attributes [= newattributes] 


object
Required. Always the name of a File or Folder object.
new attributes
Optional. If provided, new attributes is the new value for the attributes of the specified object.